# How to save previous stage in javascript.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, html5-history

In my project I am using angular $routeProvider as page navigation. In order to go back I'm using javascript.go(-1). The problem is when the button back was clicked, it's loading and rendering again all the data. Is it possible to save the previous stage in javascript.go(-1)?
Example:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/api/lecturer/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        })
        .when('/account/lecturer/project/', {
            templateUrl: 'part/lecturer_project.html',
            controller: 'projectController'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});})
```

HTML:

```
<li>
      <a onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);" style="cursor:pointer;" class="button">back
            <i class="entypo-left-dir right"></i>
      </a>
</li>
```

Comment: you can check the previous page in `angular.run` with `$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, prev)`. Save previous state in a service and pull that data in your controller

Comment: Can you give a simple example of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple implementation, you need to remember the previous page (only one), and store it in some service/factory that will provide the stored value to your controllers. Here is a simple demo with `ngRoute`:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: "main.html"
    })
    .when('/api/lecturer/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
      controller: 'dashboardController'
    })
    .when('/account/lecturer/project/', {
      templateUrl: 'part/lecturer_project.html',
      controller: 'projectController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    })
});
app.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, historyService) {
  $scope.back = historyService.get();
});
app.controller('projectController', function($scope, historyService) {
  $scope.back = historyService.get();
});

app.service('historyService', function() {
  /*  `this.back` can be an array instead, 
     which will work as a stack, 
        pushing new previous pages
        and popping then when redirected back
  */
  this.back = "";
  this.get = function() {
    return this.back;
  }
  this.set = function(val) {
    this.back = val;
  }
  this.delete = function() {
    this.back = "";
  }
})

app.run(function($rootScope, historyService) {
  // `$locationChangeStart` event works better for this example
  $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, prev) {
    //console.log(event); 
    //console.log(next); // current page
    //console.log(prev); // previous page
    historyService.set(prev); // store the previous page in a service
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <a href="#!/api/lecturer/">lecturer</a>
  <a href="#!/account/lecturer/project/">project</a>
  <hr>
  <div ng-view></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
    <p>main.html</p>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/dashboard.html">
    <p>partials/dashboard.html</p>
    <a ng-href="#!/">Main</a>
    <a ng-href="{{back}}">Go back</a>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="part/lecturer_project.html">
    <p>part/lecturer_project.html</p>
    <a ng-href="#!/">Main</a>
    <a ng-href="{{back}}">Go back</a>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but it doesn't save the previous stage. It reloads the controller every time i'm going back

Comment: @Vitali angularjs is used for single page applications. You only have one page and you are displaying different content on it, by rendering any changes. The page should **never** refresh. You are doings something wrong

Comment: I'll try to explain my self clearly. I have a lot of filters on my page in order to sort my data. When user chooses some sort, he gets the specific project data. When he clicks on it, it takes him to project page. When user clicks back, I want to display him the same sort(to save his selections) and not reloading the default data. Is it possible?

Comment: @Vitali oh okay, sure just save the data somewhere. If you can rely on **not refreshing** the page and going back, then simply store the data in a service/factory. Once you load the controller again, try to _get_ the data from a service, and if it doesn't have anything, then do the normal procedure for the controller.

Comment: @Vitali if you think that the page should be allowed to refresh, then you need to store the data either on user side, or the database. Since the data sounds temporary, then save it in cache on user's browser. For that you would need to use `localStorage` (or `sessionStorage`). Then simply pull out data from it just like with a service example (if data exists)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll try to save data in localStorage and to pull it when needed.